# VBA: how to highlight when contains a text

Tags: vba

I am getting the following error

> Run time error '13':
>
> Type mismatch

with the code below. Please help.

```
Sub test()
   ' With Range("A1:C10")
       ' .Value = ""true""
    ' End With
    If Range("h1:h10").Value = "TRUE" Then
       Cells("h, 1").Interior.Color = vbRed    
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course, `Range("h1:h10").Value` is a Variant with a type of 2-dimentional array of Variant. It cannot be compared with a String type literal. Use conditional formatting instead.

Comment: I think you mix reference styles, either use [`Cells(1,8)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells) or [`Range("H1")`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range(object)). `Cells("h, 1")` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the entire range contains at least once cell with text then you could use:

```
   if WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("h1:h10")) = 0  then   
       Cells("h, 1").Interior.Color = vbRed   
   End If
```

But if you want to check each cell and color it if it has text, you could loop through the range like:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    With Cells(i, 1)
        If .Value <> "" Then .Interior.Color = vbRed
    End With
Next i
```